# How to calculate R-Squared of test after removing dummy columns to avoid multicollinearity?

Tags: python, linear-regression, dummy-variable, train-test-split

So I want to find the R-squared of my `X_test` which includes dummy columns.

I tried not dropping the dummy columns for `X_test` while dropping them for `X_train` (that was the only solution I could think of, but obviously it didn't work).

So X is a matrix and has some categorical variables. After the train test split, I turned `X_train` and `X_test` to have dummy columns.

To avoid multicollinearity, I dropped the first column for every dummy column.

After creating `X_train_dum` and `X_test_dum`, I fit training into a linear regression model.

Here is the process:

```
X_train_dum = pd.get_dummies(X_train, 
                             columns=['day', 'month'], 
                             drop_first=True)
X_test_dum = pd.get_dummies(X_test,
                            columns=['day', 'month'],
                            drop_first=True)
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train_dum, y_train)
```

After fitting the train into lr, I thought it was appropriate to find `lr.score(X_test_dum, y_test)`

Unfortunately, it returns: `ValueError: shapes (130,28) and (27,) not aligned: 28 (dim 1) != 27 (dim 0)`

So it turns out `X_train_dum` has 27 columns while `X_test_dum` has 26 columns. I don't know why this is happening when both `X_test` and `X_train` had the same number of columns.

Comment: I calculate R-squared (R2) as "R2 = 1.0 - (numpy.var(regression_error) / numpy.var(dependent_data))" and use it to tell me what fraction of the dependent data variance is explained by the model. For example, if the R2 values is 0.95, then my model explains 95 percent of the dependent data variance. This value is exact for straight lines or flat surfaces, and is both approximate and useful for curved lines and curved surfaces.